# Priority Queue template push fuction

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with my Push function for my priority queue. I have written a templated priority queue for which the class is as follows:

```
template <typename V>
class MyPriorityQueue
{
  V* value;
  int siz;
  int cap;
public:
  MyPriorityQueue(int = 2);
  MyPriorityQueue(const MyPriorityQueue<V>&); // copy constructor
  ~MyPriorityQueue();
  void push(const V&);
  V top() const {return value[siz-1];}
  V pop();
  bool empty() const;
  void clear();
  int size() const {return siz;}
};
```

Here is my constructor

```
template <class V>
MyPriorityQueue<V>::MyPriorityQueue(int n)
{
    cap = n;
    value = new V[cap];
    siz = 0;
}
```

In my constructor I initialize `cap` to `2` and the `siz` to `0` and initialize the value.

Here is my push function:

```
template <class V>
void MyPriorityQueue<V>::push(const V &newValue)
{
    int index = siz;
    if (cap == siz)
    {
        V *temp = new V[2 * cap];
        for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
            temp[i] = value[i];
        delete[] value;
        value = temp;
        cap = 2 * cap;
    }
    value[index] = newValue;

    while (true)
    {
        if (index <= 0)
            break;
        int parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2;
        cout << parentIndex << endl;
        if (value[index] < value[parentIndex])
            break;
        swap(value[parentIndex], value[index]);
        index = parentIndex;
    }
    siz++;
}
```

I create a priority queue

```
MyPriorityQueue<int> pq;
```

and then push some values in it as follows

```
pq.push(14);
pq.push(6);
pq.push(3);
pq.push(19);
pq.push(9);
```

I use the following code to check it

```
while(!pq.empty())
{
    cout << pq.top() << endl;
    pq.pop();
}
```

since it is a priority queue my answer should be 19, 14, 9, 6, 3 since it is hi to lo
instead, it is giving me 9, 6, 3, 3, 3.
I am confused and I think the problem is in the computation of the parent index but I cant figure it out. If you require the full code I can post that too but its too long.

I am adding my pop function too.

```
template <class V>
V MyPriorityQueue<V>::pop()
{
    V val = value[0];
    // create an int index, initialized to zero -- for traversing the tree
    int index = 0;
    //start loop -- to refill the position at the top of the tree -- the one that's getting popped
    while (true)
    {
        //compute the left and right child indexes of index
        int left_childIndex = 2 * index + 1;
        int right_childIndex = 2 * index + 2;
        //if there is no left child, break from the loop -- we reached the bottom of the heap
        if (left_childIndex >= siz)
            break;
        //  if there's no right child, copy the VALUE at the left child index to the VALUE at index and set index to the left child index -- left child "wins" by default because there's no right child
        if (right_childIndex >= siz)
        {
            value[index] = value[left_childIndex];
            index = left_childIndex;
        }
        //else if the VALUE at the right child index < the VALUE at the left child index, copy the value at the left child index to the value at index and set index to the left child index -- left child "wins"
        else if (value[right_childIndex] < value[left_childIndex])
        {
            value[index] = value[left_childIndex];
            index = left_childIndex;
        }
        //else copy the VALUE at the right child index to the VALUE at index and set index to the right child index -- right child "wins"
        else
        {
            value[index] = value[right_childIndex];
            index = right_childIndex;
        }
    }
    //decrement siz -- now, if index just happens to equal siz, we're done, but no harm in continuing anyway
    siz--;
    // copy the VALUE at siz to the VALUE at index -- it's the right-most value in the bottom-most row -- move it to "fill the hole"
    value[index] = value[siz];
    //start loop -- to promote the newly-repositioned value at index
    while (true)
    {
        //if index <= 0, it's reached the top -- break from the loop -- a value got promoted all the way to the top
        if (index <= 0)
            break;
        //compute the parent index of index
        int parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2; // using integer division with truncation
        //if the VALUE at index < the VALUE at parent index, break from the loop (no more promotions)
        if (value[index] < value[parentIndex])
            break;
        //swap the values at the parent index and index -- promote and demote
        swap(value[parentIndex], value[index]);
        // set index equal to the parent index -- traversing "up" the tree
        index = parentIndex;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: comparator?@codekaizer

Comment: I dont see where you grow the size of the buffer when you push something that should increase the capacity.

Comment: if (cap == siz)
cap = 2 * cap; when the capacity eaqual to size it doubles it. @PaulRooney

Comment: `cap` is only an int. The actual buffer size isn't grown though. For that you'd need a new `value = new V[cap];` a copy and a `delete[]` to allocate a larger buffer and delete the old one. It stays at size 2 or whatever you pass in the constructor. You may have some UB if you access indices > 1.

Comment: Ok, I edited it but it still doesn't work it's giving me the same result.@PaulRooney

Comment: of course it was only a comment on the general correctness of the code and not for the specific issue you mention in the question. I think basically what you are trying to do is append the new item to the array and then sort the elements. The sorting part doesnt look like you are doing enough to do a successful sort. You could use `std::sort` or if you are wanting to avoid standard algorithms in favour of doing it yourself then you just need to figure out a good sorting implementation.

Comment: Another option is to use the fact its already sorted (avoiding a full sort on each push) and just find the required insertion index, then shuffle down all the other elements and insert the element where needed.